# Perl script does not create csv file

Tags: perl

I have the following code in my perl script which obviously generates a csv file:

```
open(OUTPUT,">Test.csv");
```

When I click on the perl script, it generates the output file.

But when I call this script from a command prompt or C# or JAVA, SQL Script (xp_cmdshell), the script does not generate the output file.

I already have full permission for EVERYONE on the folder.

Comment: Did you try running an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Is the working directiory all times the same?

Comment: The answer is Yes . from windows standpoint I don't see any problem but why Open command does not work .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't check the success of the operation. Everytime use

```
open OUTPUT, '>', 'Test.csv' or die $!;
```

or turn on [autodie](http://p3rl.org/autodie).

Comment: lexical filehandle to go with 3 arg open - `open my $output, '>', 'Test.csv' or die $!;`

Comment: I changed the script to : open OUTPUT, '>', 'Test.csv' or die $!; but still not working !